# How to declare an unknown sized array of user defined objects in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

For my module, I need to declare an unknown sized array of user defined objects with two properties: datatype and FullName. I want to be able to set these properties to null upon creation.

I tried the below code.

var result = [{
    dtype:null,
    fname:null,
}];

I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dtype' of undefined.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `var foo = [];`

Comment: How can i initialize the properties?

Comment: No repro.  You're probably not actually using javascript but something else, maybe typescript?  Open the javascript console in whatever browser you are in.  Paste what you added to your question.  Tada.  Works.  Your error lies in another castle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So javascript doesn't support defining or restricting types that go into an array, and you don't have to specify a size either, you can just keep adding those object to it natively

But if you wanted to restrict the types that went into it there is a way

```
function addThing(thing) {
    if(thing.hasOwnProperty("fullName") && thing.hasOwnProperty("dataType")) {
        array.push(thing);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9sL920qt/

Answer (score 0):

Applying Noah s logic, I tried this solution which worked for me.

```
  var result = [];
```

Have a temp  object:

```
 var resultItem = {};
```

set the values of temp object.

```
resultItem.fname = resultsinJson.Data[i][keys];
 resultItem.dtype =  resultsinJson.Data[i][keys] ;
```

and then add that object to the final array

```
 result[i] = resultItem;
```